# How do I use inheritance in programming model with JPA?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to implement this model using JPA 2.1. I'm using the *JSR 338* specification and the reference implementation *Eclipselink*.

Only entities of the third level and associative classes will be persisted.
[image]

```
@MappedSuperclass

public abstract class PessoaMaster implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long id;
private List<Telefone> telefones;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID_Pai", unique=true, nullable=false)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long identificador) {
    id = identificador;
}
/**
 * @return the telefones
 */
@OneToMany
public List<Telefone> getTelefones() {
    return telefones;
}

/**
 * @param telefones the telefones to set
 */
public void setTelefones(List<Telefone> telefones) {
    this.telefones = telefones;
}
}
```

I can use instead of Inheritance MappedSuperclass here?

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)    
public abstract class FornecedorSuper extends PessoaMaster{

    //attributes and relationships

}
```

Entity that is persisted.

```
public class FornecedorPecas extends FornecedorSuper {

private Double Valor;

@Column(name="ValorPeca")
public Double getValor() {
    return Valor;
}

public void setValor(Double valor) {
    Valor = valor;
}
}
```

It is necessary to mark FornecedorPeças class with @ Entity?

When I insert the MappedSuperclass in the FornecedorSuper. This exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - .5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives ith ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@affc70 Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [modelo] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class br.miltex.dominio.model.FornecedorPecas] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put annotations on attributes and methods. For this reason was occurring exceptions.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q1.** I can use instead of Inheritance MappedSuperclass here?

Although I didn't find any examples in the specification with that, the JPA specification says:

> The MappedSuperclass annotation designates a class whose mapping
>   information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped
>   superclass has no separate table defined for it.

So it says that the mapping information is applied to Entities, but it does not say that a `MappedSuperclass` is not allowed to extend another `MappedSuperclass`, so I believe you can use in your `FornecedorSuper` class the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

> **Q2.** It is necessary to mark FornecedorPeças class with @ Entity?

Yes, it is necessary.

Comment: Hi Andrei.The above exception is thrown.Thanks!

Comment: Andrei, his answer did not solve my problem. The specification has free access for everyone. What you quoted I had already read. His answer was an aid. So I marked it as helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Andrei, because you deleted the previous comment?